# Populate language translation array dynamically from the db in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, translation

In my laravel (laravel 6) application I have English and French languages.

Currently I'm inserting the values into a language array manually. But later on I'm expecting to insert all the texts to the db (English and French) and populate the language arrays dynamically.

```
return [
  'welcome' => 'Welcome'
];
```

How can I populate laravel's language array dynamically from the database? and what is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this package for that:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

It accomplishes everything you are asking for.